# Fpdi Error Message: Page number "3" out of available page range (1 - 2)

Tags: php, fpdi

I am working in codeigniter 3 and using FPDI library to merge multiple pdf into single. But getting error at this line $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i); . I had tried to fix this with different ways but nothing is working. Below is my code

```
function generateSinglePdf($List)
{
$pdfValue = explode(',',$List);
$path = $file = FCPATH."createpdf/";
foreach($pdfValue as $pdfVal)
{
foreach(glob("$path/{$pdfVal}*") as $imgfile)
{

$ext = substr(strrchr($imgfile, '.'), 1);
if($ext=='pdf')
{
    $imgName[] = basename($imgfile);

}   

}

}   
$count = count($imgName);
$filelocation = FCPATH."/newmultigenerate";
$time = date("d-m-Y")."-".time();
$mainfilename="ID".$id."-multipdf-".$time;
$filename=$mainfilename.".pdf";
$fileNL = $filelocation."/".$filename;

$pdf = new MPdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('OrderCal');
$pdf->SetSubject('Invoice Pdf');
$pdf->SetKeywords('Invoice Pdf');
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(2, 10, 2,true);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 10);
$pdf->my_header_title = '';


for($i=0; $i<=$count;$i++)
{
if($imgName[$i]=="")
continue;
$imgUrl =  FCPATH."createpdf/".$imgName[$i];
$pdf->setSourceFile($imgUrl);
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

}   

$pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');
}
```

Comment: You are confusing the number of pages in a PDF and the number of PDFs you are trying to merge.

Comment: where i am doing wrong. Please let me know. I have used fpdi first time

Comment: after doing R&D of 6 hours now it's working on local server. But on live server $pdf->setSourceFile  is giving error now. It's not picking up the path.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: it's working now. In $pdf->setSourceFile need to pass directory path not the link

Answer (score 1):

I have changed this in my code and it's working now. We need to run loop of images array and then in loop need to count image one by one. In my above code image count was wrong.

```
foreach($imgName as $val)
{
$imgUrl =  FCPATH."createpdf/".$val;
$cnt = $pdf->setSourceFile($imgUrl);
for($i=1; $i<=$cnt;$i++)
{

$pdf->AddPage();
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}   

} 

$pdf->Output($fileNL, 'F');
```

Comment: You should add a little bit of context to better understand what you are doing here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).